# How to calculate the value of mixhash in block header?

Tags: mining, ethereum-classic, nonce, powhash

As of my knowledge how POW works is When mining the miner will have the hash1 which is block hash and he need to fine the hash2 which is hash of nonce (a random number).

So that the root hash of hash1 and hash2 need to meet the requirement (number of zeros in frond ).

In many article I found that mixhash with the nonce is used to verify the block..

So Whats the use of mixhash and how it is used to verify the block? And when the value of mixhash is calculated?

Pls correct me of anything is wrong..